# Show that the probability of a limit goes to one (1)

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

This seems a fairly trivial exercise, but I want to see how to show this intuitive result.

We are given $Y\in N(0,2-2\rho)$, where $\rho$ is a number (actually a correlation coefficient). I want to show that for any $\epsilon>0$

$$P(|Y|\leq\epsilon)\rightarrow1$$

if $\rho \uparrow 1$.

Intuitively this result *feels* like it should be true, since it makes sense: In the limit the variance approaches zero (0), so all probability mass gets concentrated on the mean $\mu=0$. Do I need to apply some kind of convergence mode for this?

Comment: Can you use Chebyshev's inequality?  If so, do so to get a two-step proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
P((|Y| \le \epsilon ) &= P((|Y| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2-2\rho}\cdot (2-2\rho) ) \\
&\ge 1- \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2-2\rho} \right)^2} \\
&=1-\left(\frac{2-2\rho}{\epsilon} \right)^2
\end{align}

Now, just let $\rho$ tend to $1$.

Comment: I am a bit rusty on this topic, what happens after the inequality? Did you use that Y is normally distributed in addition with taking the complement? Could you explain this further? Or is it Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: That is [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality). I did not use any other property of $Y$ explicitly besides its value of mean and variance.

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you. You used the Chebyshev's inequality in a different form from my probability book. In the book they use P(|X-E[X]|>a) <= Var[X]/a^2. Is this form equivalent to yours? This seems to give an upper bound.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $-1$ and then add $1$ to both sides. Yes, they are equivalent.